# Unknown Typename when declared in header

Tags: c++, c, typename

For some odd reason I recieve unknown type name for a typedef void variable located in a header file. Naturally i searched around the net and while it can be noted that I found similar issues it should also be noted that I am not using an IDE only Vim and Clang and don't have precompiled headers. In a separate test for the ctrie_int header, everything compiles but when I extend the implementation adding its header to the implementation file of another header I get the weird error seen below. I'm sure its a simple issue but i'm not sure what it is, any suggestions?

```
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++11 lzwtest.cpp -o lzwtest dict;
Project Compilation
.
.
.
.
.
Compiling CPP file lzwtest.cpp ...
In file included from lzwtest.cpp:2:
In file included from ./LZW.h:23:
In file included from ./ctrie_int.h:36:
./ctrie_int.ii:7:1: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
Trie_Int * newTrie_Int(int defVal){return new Trie<int>(defVal);}
^
./ctrie_int.ii:7:43: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'Trie<int> *'
Trie_Int * newTrie_Int(int defVal){return new Trie<int>(defVal);}
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./ctrie_int.ii:9:21: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
void deleteTrie_Int(Trie_Int * trie){delete ((Trie<int> *)trie);}
                    ^
./ctrie_int.ii:11:19: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
int Trie_Int_size(Trie_Int * t){return ((Trie<int> *)t)->size();}
                  ^
./ctrie_int.ii:13:30: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
int Trie_Int_getDefaultValue(Trie_Int * t){return ((Trie<int> *)t)->getDefaultValue();}
                             ^
./ctrie_int.ii:15:23: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
int Trie_Int_contains(Trie_Int * t,const char * key){return ((Trie<int> *)t)->contains(key); }
                      ^
./ctrie_int.ii:17:18: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
int Trie_Int_get(Trie_Int * t,char * key){return ((Trie<int> *)t)->get(key); }
                 ^
./ctrie_int.ii:19:19: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
void Trie_Int_put(Trie_Int * t,char * s,int val){ ((Trie<int> *)t)->put(s,val);}
                  ^
./ctrie_int.ii:21:37: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
const char * Trie_Int_longestPrefix(Trie_Int * t,char * s){return  ((Trie<int> *)t)->longestPrefix(s).c_str();}
                                    ^
./ctrie_int.ii:23:23: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
int Trie_Int_compress(Trie_Int * t){return  ((Trie<int> *)t)->compress();}
                      ^
10 errors generated.
```

Below is the header for the file being included

ctrie_int.h

```
#ifndef COM_WORDGAME_UTILITY_CTRIE_H
#define COM_WORDGAME_UTILITY_CTRIE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{ //this is used to identify following code as C specific code which will enforce C style name mangling
#endif

//Declare a new void Type To Emulate C class
typedef void Trie_Int;
...Removed in attempt to shorten Question
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

This file uses the previous but even simple code or just the inclusion of the header file of the last causes the error described in the beginning

```
#ifndef COM_WORDGAME_UTILITY_CTRIE_H
#define COM_WORDGAME_UTILITY_CTRIE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{ //this is used to identify following code as C specific code which will enforce C style name mangling
#endif

void compress(char src[],char dst[]);

void decompress(char src[],char dst[]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif

//BELOW CODE WILL BE ADDED IN ANOTHER FILE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ctrie_int.h" // This causes an issue cannot find Trie_Int the functions return an odd message describing the Trie_Int was defered to an actual pointer integer
```

for clarity the first few lines of ctrie.ii looks like this

```
//#include "ctrie_int.h" //Should not be included would create cycle since ctrie_int.h declares it at the final line 
#include "Trie.hpp" //C++ code
//THIS HAS TO BE COMPILED WITH C++ COMPILER TO BE COMPILED PROPERLY ANYWAY GAURDS UNEEDED
extern "C"{
//Create new Trie_Int Object
Trie_Int * newTrie_Int(int defVal){return new Trie<int>(defVal);}
....Removed In Attempt to shorten question
}
```

Comment: Check what/how/when is actually included. I am almost certain that your header was not included.

Comment: I figured but when i add #include "ctrie_int.h" to another file and test all of their functions it works fine. However when I add it to the definition of the header it causes issues...I just decided to attempt to declare and define the functions in the same file btw which is why the includes are at the end of a header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the first stages of the error message:

```
Compiling CPP file lzwtest.cpp ...
In file included from lzwtest.cpp:2:
In file included from ./LZW.h:23:
In file included from ./ctrie_int.h:36:                     <<< Here
./ctrie_int.ii:7:1: error: unknown type name 'Trie_Int'
```

It appears that the file `ctrie_int.ii` is being included from your header *before* `Trie_Int` has been defined.

Comment: hmm that seems odd the ctrie_int.ii actually defines the functions in ctri_int.h and i actually originally had it #include at the end of the header file, which is actually what line 36 is, before i pulled everything apart trying to fix it. Is their any reason why adding ctrie_int.h to the definition file of another header would cause a weird order of includes versus it working fine for a simple test file to test the functions?

Comment: What does the first few lines of `ctrie_int.ii` look like?  Perhaps you could post that in your question.

Comment: Updated also note I removed the header to prevent a cycle since ctrie_int.ii is really just the definition of the methods in the header also the issue still arises if i remove the include from the header, add the header to ctrie_int.ii and link it in compilation

Comment: Haha a full day of trouble shooting woke up this morning before I headed out realized The header guards were identical for ctrie_int.h and lzwtest.h

Comment: hahaha dammit same problem for me, two files with identical header guards